# How to store part of a string in a variable on Lua

Tags: string, lua

I have a phrase, where only some words will change, and I need to store those words on a variable.

Example:

```
phrase = "I cannot connect to server XPTO\TEST for the last five hours"
```

The only part that will change is `XPTO\TEST` and I need to store it on a variable so that I can use it later.

Any ideas, or is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are having problem on what, how to extract `XPTO\TEST` from the phrase? How do you want to use the variable later?

Comment: Try `servername = phrase:match'server%s+(%S+)'`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need some form of placeholders, if that is a case, then you can use `string.format` or `string.gsub`.

```
 local t = {name="lua", version="5.3"}
 x = string.gsub("$name-$version.tar.gz", "%$(%w+)", t)
 --> x="lua-5.3.tar.gz"
```

With PHP for example you can achieve what you want without any extra work done, because there is a feature called string interpolation ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)).

But at the same time Lua doesn't have one, that's why you can't do that without extra string post-processing.